# How to determine whether the other then() methods can be omitted?

Tags: javascript, es6-promise, clipboard

The following codes illustrate a form which allows optionally pasting the value from the clipboard before automatically submitting. It uses two `then()` methods. Please use Chrome to test it because Firefox does not support it yet.

```js
const input = document.querySelector('input'),
      submitButton = document.querySelector('button[type="submit"]'),
      pasteAndSubmitButton = document.querySelector('button[type="button"]');

pasteAndSubmitButton.addEventListener('click', function ()
{
    navigator.clipboard.readText()
        .then(clipText => input.value = clipText)
        .then(() => submitButton.click());
});
```

```html
<form>
    Address: <input type="text" name="address" required>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    or
    <button type="button">Paste and Submit</button>
</form>
```

I'm wondering whether it is safe to omit the second `then()` method and move the code inside into the first one like this:

```js
navigator.clipboard.readText()
    .then(clipText =>
    {
        input.value = clipText;
        submitButton.click();
    });
```

My test shows that the result is the same. But I'm just not sure whether it is always safe to omit the second `then()` method because the [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) examples I have seen so far use two `then()` methods.

Comment: I don't see any reason, why it shouldn't be in the same.

Comment: Yes, that's fine.  There's only synchronous code in the first `.then()` so it can easily be combined with the 2nd.  You only need multiple chained `.then()` handlers when they have asynchronous operations in them that need to be waited on before the next `.then()` runs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many `fetch` examples use two `then`s because two promises are involved: one to get the response header, and one to read the body. In other words, both `fetch` and typical follow-up methods like [`Response.text()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/text) return a promise. Two promises aren’t involved here, so you only need one `then`.